# How do I find out which Databricks groups I'm a member of?

Tags: databricks, databricks-cli

I'm trying to figure out if I'm a member of a specific group on Databricks using either the website or Databricks CLI.

I found a [reference](https://docs.databricks.com/administration-guide/users-groups/groups.html)  to managing groups via an account console, but this requires an admin account. I also found the [Databricks groups CLI](https://docs.databricks.com/dev-tools/cli/groups-cli.html), but the documentation says you need an admin account to use the API.

Answer (score 2):

(Answering my own question.) It turns out that the Databricks groups CLI documentation is incorrect and you can use it to view your own groups as a user without admin access.

The command is:

```
databricks groups list-parents --user-name <your-user-name>
```

However, I can't view parents of other users, and I can't access the other `databricks groups` commands without getting an error message about lacking valid scope.